# Collapsible fieldset and client-side wysiwyg editor not appear

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, forms

My fieldsets `<fieldset class="menu-item-form collapsible collapsed">` on Drupal is not working. No menu items behind it could be expanded. Also my wysiwyg client-side editor is not appeared when I try to add new comment. Here is my javascript files from head of the page. Collapse.js file is there, so I don't understand why it does not work as should.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/drupal.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/tabledrag.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/languages/sk_71aea03b96873f359c032d8e6fc9f0f9.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/fb/fb_stream.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/fb/fb.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/poormanscron/poormanscron.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/custom_search/js/custom_search.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/pathauto/pathauto.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery.form.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/ahah.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/progress.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/autocomplete.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/collapse.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/teaser.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/textarea.js?z"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "cron": { "basePath": "/poormanscron", "runNext": 1348749355 }, "custom_search": { "form_target": "_self", "solr": 0 }, "ahah": { "edit-attach": { "url": "/upload/js", "event": "mousedown", "keypress": true, "wrapper": "attach-wrapper", "selector": "#edit-attach", "effect": "none", "method": "replace", "progress": { "type": "bar", "message": "Please wait..." }, "button": { "attach": "Pripojiť" } } }, "teaserCheckbox": { "edit-teaser-js": "edit-teaser-include" }, "teaser": { "edit-teaser-js": "edit-body" }, "tableDrag": { "upload-attachments": { "upload-weight": [ { "target": "upload-weight", "source": "upload-weight", "relationship": "sibling", "action": "order", "hidden": true, "limit": 0 } ] } } });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Here is an error from Javascript console:

```
[30.09.2012 20:03:06] JavaScript - http://rusnaci.zoslovenska.sk/node/add/forum
Event thread: DOMContentLoaded
Uncaught exception: Error: Invalid DOM node passed to FB.XFBML.parse()
Error thrown at line 43, column 232 in i(p, q) in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js:
    throw new g(q);
called from line 118, column 1805 in x(y, z, aa) in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js:
    g.isTrue(y.nodeType&&y.nodeType===1&&!!y.getElementsByTagName,'Invalid DOM node passed to FB.XFBML.parse()');
called from line 118, column 4418 in <anonymous function: parse>(y, z) in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js:
    x(y||document.body,z||function(){},true);
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 56, column 2064 in <anonymous function>() in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js:
    var ia=ES5(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),'map',true,function(pa){return typeof pa==='function'&&/^function/.test(pa.toString())?i.unguard(pa):pa;}),ja=da.apply(ga,ia),ka,la=true;
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 49, column 1505 in <anonymous function>() in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js:
    return t.apply(this,arguments);
called from line 26, column 6 in <anonymous function: Drupal.behaviors.fb>() in http://rusnaci.zoslovenska.sk/modules/fb/fb.js?J:
    FB.XFBML.parse(elem);
called via Function.prototype.call() from line 1, column 16237 in <anonymous function: each>(d, a, c):
    for(var b=d[0];i<length&&a.call(b,i,b)!==false;b=d[++i])
called from line 1, column 1780 in <anonymous function: each>(a, b):
    return D.each(this,a,b)
called from line 24, column 4 in <anonymous function: Drupal.behaviors.fb>(context) in http://rusnaci.zoslovenska.sk/modules/fb/fb.js?J:
    $(context).each(function() {
called from line 41, column 6 in <anonymous function: Drupal.attachBehaviors>() in http://rusnaci.zoslovenska.sk/misc/drupal.js?J:
    this(context);
```

Comment: Do you have any javaScript error in your JavaScript Console ?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my question. But I don't think it is related to collapsible problem.

Comment: I have the same problem... it's definitely a local issue. I have a multi-site install and it has happened on two of my sites and not all of them. I'm going through all my modules and CSS trying to figured out where things went wrong...

Comment: This problem exists in Opera browser only (it work previously without problem). Firefox and Chrome work with collapsible fieldsets correctly.